# How to successfully combine slick read action and then slick write action in for comprehension

Tags: scala, slick

Consider I have the following tables: A, B and AB.
Tables AB is a link table between A and B.

When I execute a simple insertOrUpdate action, it succeeds. I have 1 row inserted in the table.

```
val a = TableQuery[A]
val b = TableQuery[B]
val ab = TableQuery[AB]
Await.result(db.run(ab.insertOrUpdate(ABLink(1,1)),Duration.Inf)
println(Await.result(db.run(ab.length.result, Duration.Inf)))
//prints 1
```

But when I read from table A and B, get the ids and then insertorUpdate into table AB using for comprehension, The row is not inserted. The program completes without any errors.

```
val a = TableQuery[A]
val b = TableQuery[B]
val ab = TableQuery[AB]
val action = for {
aId <- a.map(_.id).result.headOption
bId <- b.map(_.id).result.headOption
}
yield ab.insertOrUpdate(ABLink(aId.get,bId.get))
Await.result(db.run(action),Duration.Inf)
println(Await.result(db.run(ab.length.result, Duration.Inf)))
//prints 0
```

Can someone throw light on this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because map operation is performed on the last value of the for comprehension, the insertOrUpdate Statement wasn't executed by run. When I use flatMap , it works.

When using Map. it creates a nested DBIOAction. 
The inner sqlAction is not executed.
`DBIOAction[FixedSqlAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write], NoStream, Effect.Read with Effect.Read]`

When using flatMap, it creats a flattend DBIOAction which gets executed.
`DBIOAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Read with Effect.Read with Effect.Write]`

```
val a = TableQuery[A]
val b = TableQuery[B]
val ab = TableQuery[AB]
val action = for {
aId <- a.map(_.id).result.headOption
bId <- b.map(_.id).result.headOption
}
yield ABLink(aId.get,bId.get)
Await.result(db.run(action.flatMap(ab.insertOrUpdate(_)),Duration.Inf)
println(Await.result(db.run(ab.length.result, Duration.Inf)))
//prints 1
```